# local variable 'specific_h' referenced before assignment in Find S Algorithm

Tags: python

I am trying to implement Find S algrithm but my code is giving me the following error:
"local variable 'specific_h' referenced before assignment"

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('lab1.csv')
concepts = np.array(data)[:,:-1]
target = np.array(data)[:,-1]
def train(con,tar):
    for i,val in enumerate(tar):
        if val=='yes':
            specific_h = con[i].copy()
            break
            
    for i,val in enumerate(con):
        if tar[i]=='yes':
            for x in range(len(specific_h)):
                if val[x] != specific_h[x]:
                    specific_h[x] = '?'
                else:
                    pass
    return specific_h
print(train(concepts,target))
```

Where is the issue? I have defined the variable earlier.

Comment: You have the variable inside a loop wrapped in an `if` statement. So if there are no values in `tar` to iterate or if the `if` fails, then you have no value in `specific_h` maybe try to default it before the start of the loop… `specific_h = “”` seems like it might work.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable `specific_h = []` before your `for` loop, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can decalare `specific_h = None` just after the `def train(con,tar):`